# Where did ASP.NET Web Service go in .Net Framework 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

open Visual Studio 2010.
Click File->New->Web Site...
In the dialog window that opens, select the following:
.Net Framework 3.5.
 Web Location = File System. 
 Type C#.

Notice in this list that "ASP.NET Web Service" is listed.

Now switch the framework to 4.0.

Notice that "ASP.NET Web Service" is not listed.

Can anyone shed light on what Microsoft is up to? 
Did this get rebranded to another name in 4.0? 
Am I supposed to use a new whiz-bang technology with 4.0, similar to ASP.NET Web Services?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is considered obsolete.

The basic idea and a good advice is to build a WCF service instead. More flexible and WCF incorporates multiple versions of SOAP.

If you still want to make a Fx4 WebService application, just create the Fx3.5 one and upgrade it to Fx4.

It's also possible to start with the Empty WebProject and add 1 or more ASMX WebServices through the *Add new Item* menu.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Visual Studio here, but IIRC it's hidden somewhere like this:

- Select "Add Service Reference" in the solution explorer context menu
- Click the "Advanced..." button (the button in the lower left corner of the dialog)
- Click the "Add Web Reference" button

See also [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2008/03/18/where-the-heck-is-add-web-reference-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) for more details and screenshots.

Comment: That's the consuming (client) part. The OP really wants to make a server.

Comment: Thanks @Henk, I misread the question. OTOH, we are also using "Web Site" (not Web Application) projects with VS2010/.NET4, and I'm sure the "ASP.NET Web Service" is still available in the "Add new item" dialog.

Answer (score -2):

You can also create a simple Web Application in 4.0 and add a asmx page there.